# How to render HTML changes before the window alert is triggered, without using setTimeOut in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any possible way of rendering HTML element changes before the alert is triggered, without using `setTimeOut`?
I am adding an event listener `processPlayerMove` to div elements as shown in the first for-loop below. `GameBoard.checkWinner` has a window alert call to broadcast if there is a winner after a move. However, it is being called even before the UI changes in the `displayPlayerMove` function.

Is there a possible work around to this problem other than adding a setTimeOut in the `GameBoard.checkWinner` call? I do not like to call `setTimeOut` as I am not sure how long the rendering would be.

Thank you !!!

```
for(let i = 0; i < boardItems.length; i++) {
    boardItems[i].addEventListener('click', 
        processPlayerMove, {once: true});

}        
            
function processPlayerMove() {
    displayPlayerMove(this);
    switchTurn(turn);
    GameBoard.checkWinner();
}


function displayPlayerMove(element) {
  element.innerText = turn;
  element.setAttribute('class', 'board-item colored');
  GameBoard.setValue(parseInt(element.id));
}

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not like to call setTimeOut as I am not sure how long the rendering would be.

Once a change is made, the rendering should be near instantaneous. Wait for just before the next repaint with `requestAnimationFrame`, then queue a task to occur right after the repaint, thanks Kaiido:

```js
document.body.innerHTML += 'abc';
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    alert('test');
  });
});
```

But a **much, much better** solution would be to avoid `alert` (and similar functions) entirely - they have problems like these, where they *block* the browser, preventing user interaction and making UI changes more difficult. It would be better to create a proper modal in the DOM instead, and make *that* modal come up. For example, instead of

```
alert('Player 1 wins!')
```

you could do something like

```
winnerContainer.textContent = 'Player 1 wins!';
// unhide the container (have it hidden initially)
winnerContainer.style.display = 'block';
```

where `winnerContainer` is an element on the page with the appropriate modal styling applied.

Comment: I remember I already told you so, but no, a timer of 0 is not safe. You need to wait for after the next painting frame, so `requestAnimationFrame(()=>setTimeout(cb,0))` IS safe (or `requestPostAnimationFrame(cb)` in most modern browsers)

Comment: Oh wow, I see what you mean. I'd never encountered any issues with it, at least in all the browsers on Windows that I've tried, I guess I never had the situation of the setTimeout inside the RAF which *again* tries to do something after a timeout.

Comment: Yes I guess you generally respond to click events (which are synced with the monitor nowadays) or previous rAF callbacks, but things like network responses are not, so it's not uncommon to fall in between frames, but anyway, how often do you use `alert()`?